# Using HTTParty to post json to Google Places

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, google-maps, httparty

I'm trying to figure out how to write a google places POST request using HTTParty.  I was able to do a GET request but can't figure out how to work around the fact that Google Places has a nested parameter to post into.  Here is the json syntax from the api documentation. Can someone help me translate this into the syntax that can work with HTTParty.post

```
POST https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?sensor=true_or_false&key=api_key HTTP/1.1
Host: maps.googleapis.com

{
  "location": {
    "lat": -33.8669710,
    "lng": 151.1958750
  },
  "accuracy": 50,
  "name": "Google Shoes!",
  "types": ["shoe_store"],
  "language": "en-AU"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [httparty gem](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/) includes [an example](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/examples/basic.rb) that posts nested JSON to a server.

Comment: Thanks.  However now I'm getting a content-length required error.  any ideas on how to workaround that?